# Hadoop results confusion

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I found this difference confused me

Initially, I wanted to calculate the number of records in the reducer by accumulating 1 in each step, the code is as follows:

The input pair is `<Text, DoubleWritable>` and all the records has the same key "one". There are 160000 records

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<DoubleWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, DoubleWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    double count = 0;   
    while(values.hasNext()){
        count = count + 1;
    }
    output.collect(new Text("Count"), new DoubleWritable(count));
}
```

The output is 22

After I change the input of reducer to 
       `<Text, Text>`, The key value is the same for all records "one", and the value is "1"

The code becomes:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, DoubleWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    double count = 0;
    String s = "";  
    while(values.hasNext()){
        s = values.next().toString();
        count = count + Integer.parseInt(s);
    }

    output.collect(new Text("Count"), new DoubleWritable(count));
}
```

Now the answer is right: 160000

It seems like the number of iterations of while loop should be the same in each case. Why are the results different?

Comment: What does your mapper and job config look like?

Comment: Is your reducer also the combiner?

Comment: @climbage  Sorry for the late reply.Yes, I set the combiner to be the same as the reducer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the logic of your two examples is actually different.  In the first case, you're only counting the number of key/value pairs passed to the reducer.

To be logically equivalent, you need to change `count = count + 1` to `count = count + iter.next().get()` in order to get a sum of the values.

The reason for this is because your reducer is also the combiner.  So by the time the key/value pairs get to your reducer, they have already been partially summed (combined).

```
Count 1700
Count 42
Count 5640
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I deactivated the combiner and it got the correct result. So instead of counting the number of records my first case is actually counting the number of chunks after combiner?

Comment: Yep, that's whats happening.